# "Migrated from" or "Closed" message appears twice after inline editing

Tags: bug, status-norepro, editing

### Steps to reproduce

1. Find a migrated or closed question
2. Edit it (or just save, without editing anything)
3. Result: "migrated from", or "closed" message appears twice

Refresh the page and the duplicate message is gone again. Anybody experience the same? Running Chrome Dev (14.0.803) on OS X 10.6.

---

### Examples

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Is it still there when you refresh?

Comment: @random No, just a JavaScript thing. It disappears after refreshing.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Could you check whether this topic is still relevant, and if not, flag it for status assignment/closing?

Comment: @DanielBeck Seems that was fixed a long time ago. Flagged for closing.